# ar-XA language code: which Arabic variant is it?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

Google in its text to speech documentation uses ar-XA code for Arabic. Does anybody know which local variant of Arabic this code stands for? Or is it Modern Standard Arabic...? There's no "XA" code among ISO country codes...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ar-XA is Modern Standard Arabic (usually denoted as ar-001).